# Is it necessary to make a primitive instance variable volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Just to experiment with multithreading concepts, I'm implementing my own version of AtomicInteger that uses pessimistic locking. It looks something like this:

```
public class ThreadSafeInt {
    public int i; // Should this be volatile?

    public ThreadSafeInt(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        return i;
    }

    public synchronized int getAndIncrement() {
        return this.i++;
    }
    // other synchronized methods for incrementAndGet(), etc...
}
```

I wrote a test that takes an instance of ThreadSafeInt, gives it to hundreds of threads, and makes each of those threads call getAndIncrement 100,000 times. What I'm seeing is that all the increments happen correctly, with the value of the integer being exactly `(number of threads) * (number of increments per thread)`, even though I'm not using volatile on the primitive instance variable `i`. I expected that if I did not make `i` volatile, then I would get lots of visibility problems where, for instance, thread 1 increments `i` from 0 to 1, but thread 2 still sees the value of 0 and also increments it to only `1`, causing a final value that is less than the correct value.

I understand that visibility problems occur randomly and can depend on properties of my environment, so that my test can appear to work fine even though there is inherent potential for visibility problems. So I'm inclined to think the volatile keyword is still necessary.

But is this correct? Or is there some property of my code (maybe the fact that it's just a primitive variable, etc) which I can actually trust to obviate the need for the volatile keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> even though I'm not using volatile on the primitive instance variable i. I expected that if I did not make i volatile, then I would get lots of visibility problems

By making your `getAndIncrement()` and `get()` methods `synchronized`, all of the threads that are modifying `i` are properly locking it for both the updates and the retrieval of the value.  The `synchronized` blocks make it unnecessary for `i` to be `volatile` because they also ensure memory synchronization.

That said, you should be using an `AtomicInteger` instead which wraps a `volatile int` field.  `AtomicInteger` `getAndIncrement()` method updates the value without having to resort to a `synchronized` block which is much faster while still being thread-safe.

```
public final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
...
// no need for synchronized here
public int get() {
    return i.get();
}
// nor here
public int getAndIncrement() {
    return i.getAndIncrement();
}
```

> I would get lots of visibility problems where, for instance, thread 1 increments i from 0 to 1, but thread 2 still sees the value of 0 and also increments it to only 1, causing a final value that is less than the correct value.

If your `get()` method was not `synchronized` then your increment might be handled right but other threads would not see the value of `i` published correctly.  But with both methods being `synchronized` this ensures memory synchronization on reads and writes.  `synchronized` also does the locks so that you can do the `i++`.  Again the `AtomicInteger` handles the memory synchronization and the increment race conditions much more efficiently.

More specifically, when a `synchronized` block is entered, it crosses a read memory barrier which is the same as reading from a `volatile` field.  When a `synchronized` block is exited, it crosses a write memory barrier which is the same as writing to a `volatile` field.  The difference with the `synchronized` blocks is that there is also locking to ensure only one person is locking a particular object at one time.

Comment: Are you saying that synchronized not only guarantees that the code path can only be executed by one thread at a time, but additionally it guarantees that any variable that is touched inside of a synchronized block is treated as though it is volatile? I thought that even when you use synchronize, it is possible for two threads to observe different values in the variables - so I think what you are saying is that this is not the case.

Comment: @russell What this really means is `i++` which is normally not an atomic operation is made atomic because of `synchronized`.

Comment: "@russel when both writing and reading methods are synchronized, as in your code, normal field variables are treated as volatile. Learn "Java Memory model" to develop meaningful test programs.

Comment: I've added some to the end of my question @russell to explain about memory barriers and the similarities (and differences) between `volatile` and `synchronized`.